# How to use SyntheticEvent in flow 0.132 and newer?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, flowtype

Well I now decided to update past version 0.131.0 from flow. However this has the following breaking change:

> Disallow using any-typed values type annotations.

(https://github.com/facebook/flow/releases/tag/v0.132.0)

This leads to a break with SyntheticEvent in the following context:

```
function requestRemove(ev: SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>, extra_option: ExtraOptionSchema) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    //more code
}
```

The error shown:

```
Error:(124, 41) Cannot use `SyntheticEvent` as a type because it is an `any`-typed value. Type `SyntheticEvent` properly, so it is no longer `any`-typed, to use it as an annotation.
```

If I remove the `ev.stopPropagation()` (and all other reference to the event such a `ev.currentTarget`) it works perfectly fine, no error is shown at all. (PS: the error is shown in `0.140.0` however manual testing shows it persist until I go back to version `0.131.0`, which coincides with the changelog exempt above).

React is imported by:

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

And I've also tried to be more explicit by stating the type as: `React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>` or `SyntheticInputEvent<HTMLElement>`. But this gave the error:

```
Error:(124, 47) Cannot get `React.SyntheticEvent` because property `SyntheticEvent` is missing in  module `react` [1].
```

Comment: `SyntheticEvent` is defined in `react-dom`, which used to be provided by flow but was moved to `flow-typed` in 0.122.0. Do you have `react-dom` correctly installed?